# Python Jupyter: performance increase of "ipywidget.interactive"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am using the following example code in Jupyter. It is responding relatively delayed to the adjustments of the slider values. How can be the performance increased?  In principle I don't want to redraw the whole plot each time when one of the sliders is moved. Only the curve should then be redrawn (but how?).

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(omega, phi):
    plt.figure()
    t = np.linspace(0, 10, num = 1000)
    y = sin(omega * t + phi)
    plt.plot(t, y)
    plt.ylim(-1, 1)
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, omega=(0.1, 5, 0.1), phi=(0, 5, 0.1))

interactive_plot
```

Comment: I have several suggestions, if they suit your use-case, with them we can talk about them in details :)
1) Increase the steps i.e. omega=(0.1,5,0.5), so it does not compute at every 0.1, but rather 0.5 instead.
2) Pre-compute all the values (Not a very scalable solution but if range is limited then it should work!)

Comment: @user12758604: Thank you, but how can I seperate the update of the y curve from the rest of the plot? Could you please post an answer?

Comment: I tried to do some optimisation (shifting `plt.figure()` and `t=np.linspace(0,10,num=1000)` out of def scope, because they only need to be executed once every time function is called.) but the effect is negligible. Changing `plt.show()` to `plt.draw()` did speed things up 3x by `time.time()` measure, however, I think it's still quite sluggish to our human eyes.. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that has no delay is the following:

```
%matplotlib widget
import ipywidgets as interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

t = np.linspace(0, 10, num = 1000)
    
def f(t, omega, phi):
    return np.sin(omega * t + phi)

@interactive.interact(omega=(0.1, 5, 0.1), phi=(0, 5, 0.1))
def update(omega = 1.0, phi = 0):
    [l.remove() for l in ax.lines]
    ax.plot(t, f(t, omega, phi), color='C0')
```